# C++ Unit test for QT-Application in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I have created a Qt project (QT-Application) in Visual Studio and I want to add a C++ Unit Test to this existing project.

My question is, is it possible to add a C++ Unit Test to an existing Qt project in Visual Studio?

If yes, how can I do it ?

Could you give me an example please ?

Thank you.

Comment: We use Google Test, it works fine.

Comment: Qt has its own: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html

Comment: Typically unit tests are created as separate projects. This does not mean that they can not be used to test code from existing project though.